# In jq grid detect a row has been changed on moving from that row

Tags: jqgrid

In jq grid how detect that particular a row has been changed when we  move from that row.

Comment: You should more clear describe what you mean. What you mean under "we move from that row"? What you do? Which jqGrid API you use? Small code fragrant can be helpful in the most questions.

Comment: @Oleg - Hi, actually I have situation that I have to save to save the data manual, so when we changed first row and without saving we go to second row to edit then there should be a check that a row has been modified, do you want to save?

Comment: **Which jqGrid API you use?** The answer on your question depend on what you do exactly. **How** you modify the row? Do you use some editing mode? Which one (inline editing using `inlineNav`, inline editing using `formatter: "actions"`, inline editing using direct call of `editRow`, form editing, ...)?